SwiftUI app mainly for visionOS does not work as expected on iOS
I built a visionOS app first that I launched on visionOS App Store.
Now I would like to publish this app on App Store for iOS, but when I run on iOS, iPadOS targets, I got theses layouts.
Here's the code of this view
List(pictures) { picture in
            NavigationLink(destination: AstronomyPictureDetailView(picture: picture)) {
                AstronomyPictureAsyncImage(picture: picture)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)

        WindowGroup {
            AstronomyPicturesView()
                .environment(AppDI.shared.astronomyPicturesDependencies())
                .environment(AppDI.shared.audioPlayerDependencies())
        }




Running on iPadOS
Running on iOS
Running on visionOS










I'm expecting the list fit to screen perfectly as all normal apps

It looks like you are missing the iPad target.

That was true @loremipsum, I've added it and it works but it add a strange safe area at bottom of app
